# Knockout JS View Refresh and Filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm kind of new to Knockout, so please be patient.  I've got a table of data that I'm trying to dynamically filter from text boxes in the table's header section.  I'm only able to add one character in the text box, then the data is filtered and the control loses focus.  For example, I am not able to type "XX" because the filtering action is started and completed when the first "X" is entered and the cursor is removed from the textbox.

This is my inspiration - http://jsfiddle.net/Xpx7f/20/

Here's the markup

```
   // This where I'm filtering
   <thead>               
       <tr data-bind="foreach: columnNames">
           <td>
               // why isn't this "data-bind="textInput: filters"?
               // the observable name is filters not filter
               <input type='text' data-bind="textInput: filter" /> 
           </td>
       </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody data-bind="foreach: enrollments">
       <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: WinId"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: EffectiveYear"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: FileKeeperGroupId"></td>                    
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here's the Knockout

```
   var viewModel = (function(){
            self = this;
            self.enrollments = ko.observableArray([]);  
            self.filters = ko.observableArray([]); 

            self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {                  
                var filter = self.filters(); 
                var enrollments = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.enrollments(), function (item) {
                    for (var col in filter) {                    
                        var v = (item[col] || '').toString(); // column value
                        var f = filter[col]; // what's typed in header
                        if (v.lastIndexOf(f, 0) === 0) return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });

                if(enrollments.length > 0)
                {
                    self.enrollments(enrollments);
                }
                else{
                    return self.enrollments();
                }
            });

            var subscriptions = [];
            self.columnNames = ko.computed(function () {
                ko.utils.arrayForEach(subscriptions, function (s) { s.dispose(); });
                subscriptions = [];
                if (self.enrollments().length === 0) return [];
                var props = [];
                var obj = self.enrollments()[0];
                for (var name in obj) {         
                    var p = { name: name, filter: ko.observable('') };
                    subscriptions.push(p.filter.subscribe(filterOnChanged, p));
                    props.push(p);
                }                      
                return props;
            });

            var filterOnChanged = function (value) {
                var filters = self.filters();
                filters[this.name] = value;            
                self.filters(filters);     
            };                
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var vm = new viewModel();
            vm.getRecords();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

Comment: self.columnNames -> any reason for it to be comptued?

Comment: It keeps the field names from being hardcoded, but I can 100% wrong

Comment: Well, I am not seeing where your self.enrollments is populated. As far as I understand you build your columnNames based on first element in the enrollments.

Comment: try it the way I proposed in the answer and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is happening because your **self.columnNames** is a computed observable and it depends on **self.enrollments** observable. **self.enrollments** observable gets changed when filters are applied. And when your **self.columnNames** observable gets updated rebinding takes place and everything gets re rendered and you lose focus because DOM elements are new.

I would move the logic to build columns in a separate function:

```
function initColumns () {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(subscriptions, function (s) { s.dispose(); });
    subscriptions = [];
    if (self.enrollments().length === 0) return [];
    var props = [];
    var obj = self.enrollments()[0];
    for (var name in obj) {         
         var p = { name: name, filter: ko.observable('') };
         subscriptions.push(p.filter.subscribe(filterOnChanged, p));
         props.push(p);
     }                      
    return props;
});
```

And than call this function when you init your columnNames observable array.

```
self.columnNames = ko.observableArray(initColumns());
```

Otherwise you will get stuck in this self updating circular hell.

update based on the fiddle

ok so what you have to do is remove self.filteredItems and create instead a computed observable that looks like this:

```
self.filteredEnrollments = ko.computed(function () {                  
    var filter = self.filters(); 
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.enrollments(), function (item) {
        for (var col in filter) {                    
            var v = (item[col] || '').toString(); // column value
            var f = filter[col]; // what's typed in header
            if (v.lastIndexOf(f, 0) === 0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Than in your html, bind to the filteredEnrollments instead of the enrollments.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredEnrollments">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: WinId"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: EffectiveYear"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: FileKeeperGroupId"></td>                    
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This way you will not be changing your **enrollments** observable array which will not trigger the **columnNames** computed to rebind the DOM.

Comment: I think you're logic is correct, but I can't get it to work. The textboxes aren't there and my table has no records.  Also why does it matter where I put - self.columnNames = ko.observableArray(initColumns());??? If I put it at the top of the VM I get an array error.

Comment: The filter variable in self.filteredItems is empty so it returns false.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: I should be able to, but I need to wait until tomorrow because it's not straight-forward in the code.

Comment: I'm having difficulty extracting the right code and data to put in a fiddle.  However, this fiddle does exactly what I'm trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/Xpx7f/20/